# Salesforce Business Hours API calculations doesn't works properly?

Tags: java, apex

I am using salesforce BusinessHours API to calculate the target date when added X number of days. The below logic is not working fine ?

Note : **Business hours set to 8:00 AM to 5:00 PM.**

**Requirement** : When Case Submitted say 10 AM today (2/16/2018 10 AM) within business hour, and expected target Date is 3 days, then target date should come like 2/22/2018 10 AM only. But the below logic shows wrong data. How we can fixed this ?

```
global static Date getBusinessTargetDate(DateTime startDate, Integer businessDays){
    DateTime businessEndDateTime;
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(startDate.year(), startDate.month(), startDate.day());

    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id,Name,IsActive,IsDefault,MondayEndTime,MondayStartTime 
                        FROM BusinessHours 
                        WHERE Name = 'US Business Hours'];
    businessEndDateTime = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, startDateTime, businessDays*9*60*60*1000L);

    String strDateValue = businessEndDateTime.format().split('\\s+')[0];
    String[] strArray = strDateValue.split('/');

    return Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(strArray[1]), Integer.valueOf(strArray[0]), Integer.valueOf(strArray[2]));
}
```

Comment: @All - Any guidance on this ?